# How to concatenate all values (only the values) from any arbitrary json into a single string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

In javascript, given *any arbitrary* json string as input, I would like to create a single string containing the concatenation of only the *values* from the json represented by the input string. For example:

```
json = '{ "x": "some text", "y" : [3, "more text", {"z": 7}]}';
concatFunc(json) // should return "some text3more text7"
```

I'm hoping there is some nice Javascript feature or function I'm unaware of that allows me to do this easily - either on the json string itself or by doing a JSON.parse() and then "flattening" the javascript data structure somehow?

Comment: Your `json` variable is a string, not json.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks, have edited body of question to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

Having consulted the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on JSON.parse(), I noted the *reviver* callback argument that gets called for every value being parsed! That can be used to build up a string:

```js
function concatFunc(json) {
  let txt = "";
  JSON.parse(json, (key,val) => {
    if (typeof val !== "object")
      txt = txt + val.toString();
  });
  return txt;
}

exampleJSON = '{ "x": "some text", "y" : [3, "more text", {"z": 7}]}';
console.log(concatFunc(exampleJSON));
```

Outputs: "some text3more text7"

Comment: Your `json` variable is a string, not json.  Your question is about working with json values.  Is that still the answer you're looking for?

Comment: @jmargolisvt yes it is :-)

Comment: How can you ask and answer a question at the same minute?

Comment: Self-answering is specifically allowed for on SO.

Comment: @quirimmo After researching some more before posting, I figured out a solution, hence why I answered. There is a tickbox at the bottom of the page when asking a question that says "answer your own question". In fact "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged". For more details see,  https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @jmargolisvt JSON *is* text. You seem to think that JSON is a JavaScript literal, but it a textual data-exchange format.

Answer (score 0):

The following code produces the output specified:

```
let jsonString = '{ "x": "some text", "y" : [3, "more text", {"z": 7}]}';
let object = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var primitivs = ["string", "number", "boolean", "undefined"]; // modify as needed
var resultStr = "";

var concatObjVal = function (obj) {

    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {

        let val = obj[key];
        let type = typeof val;

        if (primitivs.indexOf(type) != -1) {
            resultStr = resultStr + val;
        }
        else {
            concatObjVal(val);
        }
    }    
}

concatObjVal(object);

console.log("Result: " + resultStr);
```